# Не работает метод 'slickGoTo' slickSlider'a в событии 'afterChange'

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Привет. Вообщем суть - лендинг сверстан на fullpage.js, и посреди секций находится блок с position:fixed, в котором находится slickSlider. По задумке, необходимо в первой секции автопрокрутка 3 слайдов(с 1 по 3, бесконечно), а при переходе на вторую секцию, идет автопрокрутка 4,5,6 слайда, тоже бесконечно.
На данный момент, на событии onLeave плагина fullpage.js идет проверка секции, и при скролле на нужную секцию метод 'slickGoTo' перекидывает на указанный слайд тоже. НО, почему то не работает код который зацикливает прокрутку

```
$('.iphone-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    if(currentSlide == 2) {
        console.log(currentSlide);
        $('.iphone-slider').slick('slickGoTo','0');
    }
    if(currentSlide == 5) {
        console.log(currentSlide);
        $('.iphone-slider').slick('slickGoTo','3');
    }
});
```

Проверка проходит, ну возврат на указанный слайд не идет.
Код слайдера

```
$('.iphone-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        arrows: false,
        speed: 600,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        vertical: true,
        pauseOnFocus: false,
        infinite: false
    });
```

Ну и приложу код проверки секции (он работает)

```
if (nextIndex == 1) {
                    $('.iphone-slider').slick('slickGoTo','0');
                    $('.animFirstLeft, .animSecondLeft').addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
                    $('.animFirstRight, .animSecondRight').addClass('animated fadeInRight');
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем после просмотра кода самого slickSlider'a выяснилось что метод

```
slick('slickGoTo');
```

не работает, так как в исходном коде слайдера напутано с переменными, и прокрутка слайдера во время событий блокирует его. Нашелся выход через direction:

```
var slickInChange = false;
var onChangeSlide = null;
var currentPage = 1;

$('.iphone-slider')
    .on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        slickInChange = true;
    })
    .on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
        slickInChange = false;
        if (onChangeSlide) {
            onChangeSlide();
        }
        if (currentSlide === (currentPage - 1) * 3 && slick.direction === 0) {
            slick.direction = slick.direction ? 0 : 1;

        }
        if(currentSlide === (currentPage * 3 - 1) && slick.direction === 1) {
            slick.direction = slick.direction ? 0 : 1;
        }
});
```

В этом случае, идет прокрутка слайдов так - сначала первый, потом второй, потом третий, и в обратном порядке, и так бесконечно. И получается что три слайда из всего количества будут зациклены, пока мы не перейдем на следующую секцию.
Надеюсь кому нибудь пригодится.